# Deploy Multiple Apps Under a Single GitHub Repository - Django + React

Tags: reactjs, django, git, web-deployment

I have built my website in 1 repository, Django and react I realized later on this is not a very common structure, and I'm stuck with deploying,

How and where I can deploy my website where I have Django and React in 1 repository?

this is my project structure - backend ( all Django stuff ) - frontend ( all react stuff )

```
PortfolioWebsite
|___PortfolioWebsite
| ____ backend
| └── All backend stuff (views..etc)
| ____ frontend
| └── all react stuff
|___PortfolioWebsite
 └── settings.py etc..
```

is it possible to deploy this and keep updating my code as I usually do in my localhost, without changing the structure?